# Counting number of lines in a transform stream. Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, transform

I have a test.log files that in my IDE says it has 2842000 lines of text.
I have a transform stream that I want to spit out an object based on with information on the number of lines and other information. When I console.log my sum of total lines it's above what 2846596 lines. Where am I getting the extra data from?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
const Transform = require('stream').Transform;


//init timer and transform stream
var TransformStream = function(){
  Transform.call(this, {objectMode: true});

  //adding timer to TransformStream prototype;
  this.timer = process.hrtime();

  // adding a buffer to the transform stream
  this.buffer = new Buffer('');
}
util.inherits(TransformStream, Transform);//inheriting Transform into TransformStream

//total lines and bytes init
var sumBytes = 0;
var totalLines = 0;

//_transform function that needs to be defined in a transform stream.
TransformStream.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, callback){
  // transform before
  // console.log("Transform:" + chunk);
  this.buffer = new Buffer(chunk);

  // transforming here
  // getting total number of lines
  var lines = (this.buffer.toString().split('\n').length);
  console.log(typeof(lines));
  console.log(totalLines + " plus " + lines);
  totalLines += lines;

  console.log(totalLines);
  // summing total length
  sumBytes += (this.buffer.length);
  //transform after 
  // console.log(this.buffer);
  var time = process.hrtime(this.timer);
  // pushing chunk out of transform
  var summaryObj = {elapsed_time: time, total_length_in_bytes: totalLines, total_lines: sumBytes}
  // console.log(summaryObj);
  // this.push(chunk);
  this.push(summaryObj);
  callback();
}


ts = new TransformStream;

ts.on('data', function(data){
  // sumBytes += data.length;
  console.log("This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: " + sumBytes);


  // console.log("This are the number lines in the chunk: " + readableData.length)


  // console.log(string);
})

ts.on('end', function(chunk){
  // WHY THE F IS CHUNK UNDEFINED HERE ON THE END EVENT!!!!!!!!!
  // clearing start
  // ending timer on end emitter for transformation
  // totalLines += string.split("\n").length;
  // console.log(totalLines);

  // console.log(time);
  // console.log(totalLines);
  console.log('we are in the end event for the transform stream ' + chunk);
})


rs = fs.createReadStream('test.log');
ws = fs.createWriteStream('transform.log');
rs.pipe(ts);
```

This is the end of the output I get in my terminal when I run this:

```
2840564
This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: NaN
number
2840564 plus 619
2841183
This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: NaN
number
2841183 plus 620
2841803
This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: NaN
number
2841803 plus 619
2842422
This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: NaN
number
2842422 plus 619
2843041
This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: NaN
number
2843041 plus 619
2843660
This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: NaN
number
2843660 plus 620
2844280
This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: NaN
number
2844280 plus 619
2844899
This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: NaN
number
2844899 plus 619
2845518
This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: NaN
number
2845518 plus 620
2846138
This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: NaN
number
2846138 plus 458
2846596
This is the total amount of bytes in test.log: NaN
we are in the end event for the transform stream undefined
```

Comment: Is `this.buffer` an `ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: I believe so. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray.

Comment: Hmm... I'm looking through node docs. Do I have to _flush the transform stream? Is that why I'm getting extra data?

Comment: What is purpose of `this.buffer.toString().split('\n').length` if `this.buffer` is an `Uint8Array`, and not the actual textual data within the `TypedArray`?

Comment: That line is to count the number of bytes in the file. I believe buffer.length converts to bytes.

Comment: `this.buffer.toStrin‌​g().split('\n').lengt‌​h` would return the `.length` of the array returned by `.split('\n')`? Not the `.byteLength` of the `ArrayBuffer`? Can you include text of `this.buffer.toStrin‌​g()`at Question?

Comment: Yes that's fine. That tells me the total amount of lines in the text file. 
Using bytelength produces the same input as just using (this.buffer.length) for bytes

Answer (score 0):

Part of issue is `this.buffer.toStrin‌​g().split('\n').lengt‌​h`, where if `buffer` is a `Uint8Array`, would not return the number of bytes of `this.buffer`, but rather the `.length` of the resulting array returned by `.split("\n")`.

```js
var buffer = new Uint8Array(100);
var lines = buffer.toString().split("\n");
console.log(`lines:${lines}\nlines.length:${lines.length}\nbuffer.byteLength:${buffer.byteLength}`);
```

You can use `buffer.byteLength` to return the number of bytes set in the `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: I believe you can count the bytes by splitting the buffer and counting the resulting array.length; I get the same output with both bytelength and splitting and counting the array. I guess it might be more cost efficient to use bytelength.